# Get facebook page news feed

Tags: objective-c, facebook, api, feed

I'm coding a little IOS application and I wanted to know how do I get a the post/the news feed from a certain facebook page.

Thanks you and I hope that someone out there have the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is not possible to access the news feed through the facebook ios api.

Comment: So there's no way to access someone timeline/news feed or access a certain page/group timeline/news feed ? I've searched a lot about it and found nothing too.